# Identifying the rows of my table with 'type' column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Let's say for example i have 3 tables:

Users - Images - Product.

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od4jK.png)

It looks like that. How do i easily identify whether the row is for the user or for the product.

My first solution was to name a single (ID) inside image/cover table and have it reference to 2 tables and add a `'type'` column with **string data type** and just store `'user'` and/or `'product'` strings inside it to determine if the `'id'` is a `user_id` or a `product_id`.

Aside from the obvious mistake of referencing 2 tables to one foreign key. Is there any other problem with my idea?

Maybe i can just add two (ID). Namely, `user_id` and `product_id` and declare both as NULL. I would be able to determine which table the row belongs to.

if `user_id` has a value of **'1'** and `product_id` is **NULL** then that row belongs to user.

Sample controller/model code snippet for inserting a user cover/image.

Controller:

```
$insert['user_id'] = $this->user_id;
$insert['product_id'] = NULL;
$insert['original'] = $image_name;
$insert['thumbnail'] = $this->upload->data('raw_name').'_thumb';

$image_id = $this->model->insert_cover($insert);

if($image_id > 0){//do something }
```

Model:

```
public function insert_cover($data){
$query = $this->db->insert('cover/image', $data);
if($query){ return $this->db->insert_id(); }else{ return 0; }
}
```

I have default requirements for uploading an image to my project folder `'/assets/uploaded_images/'` but i want to display all product images as **200x200** and all user images as **100x100** so i used image_lib in codeigniter to resize the original uploaded image and the resized image is automatically named with a suffix of `'_thumb'`.

I then store the file name of both the original and the thumbnail to my database and when displaying them on my view i just add a url string

`$cover = 'http://localhost/project_name/assets/uploaded_images/'.$file_name`

Anyway, so what is the best method can i apply here that will easily identify which table the row belongs to?

Do i opt for the 2 id with NULL values? do i add a 'type' column that is a string?

But why do i feel its tacky/loose? whenever i insert something i would have to add:

```
$insert['type'] = 'user';
```

I think its because i have no control over 'type' column.

What if i add another table named `image_type` or `cover_type` with 2 columns. Namely, `type_id` and `type_name`.

Then whenever i insert into the image table i would have to query for the `'type'` column first.

```
//inserting user image/cover

    $type = $this->model->check_type('user');

    if($type != NULL){ 
    // do something 
    }

    public function check_Type($type){
    $this->db->select('type_id');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('image_type', array('type_name' = $type));
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach($query->result() as $row){
    $type = $row->type_id;}
    return $type;
    }else{ return NULL; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having 2 columns for userId and productId isn’t really a very good solution because that will have a lot of `NULL` values which can be avoided with the use of a `type` column. Moreover, it will not allow you to add anymore image types without adding a new column for every image type.

The `type` column solution without a separate table is a good idea if you have a very few image types and you are not planning to add many more. You can even go with this solution if you want to add just a few more by referencing them from the code (as long as they are not too many).

The solution of having a separate table is the best out of the 3 if you want a generic solution that can be easily used to add more image types.

That being said, you can use a JSON column to save multiple image paths in the same table as the entity (newer versions of MySQL allow querying over JSON data. You can find out more about it here [The JSON datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html))

Comment: That brings me back to my problem of referencing a single foreign key to 2 tables. If i were to cross out the solution of 2 foreign key with null values.

Comment: Have you checked the JSON data type i mentioned as a possible solution?

Comment: I checked it on w3school. I can store it like this right? using php. 
$insert['id'] = { 'user_id':$user_id, 'product_id':NULL }

but thats still 1 column referencing 2 tables. still a problem.

Comment: No, what I meant was use the `JSON` column in each of the entity tables. For example: user table has an images `JSON` column and same goes with the product table. In the save function you only have to pick the right table and save the values. Same goes when you fetch the images, pick the right table and fetch.

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice if i just add a new table named images with image_id,original,thumbnail.

then in the user or product table, just add an image_id column?

Comment: It would if original and thumbnail are the only 2 types of images for every entity. Change that to `image_id, type, path` an you can use it for adding more image types as well.

Comment: I wouldn't need the type then. Since i inserted the image_id into the user and product table. Therefore that image_id belongs to either user/product thus making 'type' column useless.

Comment: The `type` column will hold values like `thumbnail`, `original` etc. This is only if you need a generic solution to add a new image type say `medium` or something. You would have to create a new column everytime you want to add a new image type to achieve this if you use `image_id,original,thumbnail`

Comment: I'll just forgo using the type column. Would make my table complicated. Either i would have to story the 2 image_id with 2 different type as json or a simple string with a delimiter so i can just explode() it in my code whenever i want to access them.

There's really no difference between original and thumbnail, just that the thumbnail is geared towards displays, so if i were to insert a product image it would be resized to 300x300 but if its a user image 100x100. either way, it will still be inserted into thumbnail col

Comment: Yes sure, that was just a suggestion if you wanted a solution to be generic.

Comment: Through this discussion i found my answer. I'll accept your answer.